# Deploying camel spring application in Apache Karaf 4.2.0

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, spring-camel

I am trying to deploy camel spring application in apache karaf. I am using maven to resolve the dependencies. The application runs fine in Intellij but when I deploy the application (along with all the project dependencies) in karaf the application won't start.

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way to deploy camel spring application in karaf?
And also the best approach in resolving the project dependencies?

Camel-version: 2.16.5
Karaf: 4.2.0

Comment: Extremely hard to answer without seeing any logs or what you have done. Share your steps and logs so we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is not starting, then it might be waiting for some resolvable dependency. Check the log and install the dependency manually using feature:install. Also ensure all libraries are properly mentioned in pom.xml